# How can I access the vuex store when leaving the site

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I use vue.js with nuxt and want to remove something from the vuex store upon leaving the site.

I tried

```
beforeDestroy ({ store }) {
  store.commit('auth/setUserShowSecureAccountHint', false)
}
```

which didn't work as store is not known

and also

```
beforeDestroy () {
  this.store.commit('auth/setUserShowSecureAccountHint', false)
}
```

didn't work as `store` is not known.

How can I access the vuex store upon leaving the site?

Comment: why u want to do that? Store isnt persisted. So when they leave store is gone too

Comment: by "leaving" I mean they click a nuxt link to another page. So this doesn't involve a page reload so everything in the store will still be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prefix the `store` keyword by `$` sign as follows :

```
beforeDestroy () {
  this.$store.commit('auth/setUserShowSecureAccountHint', false)
}
```